# Chart SetSourceData fails - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, charts, datasource, excel-charts

The following statement fails:

```
wksGraphTotal.ChartObjects("TotQuestion").SetSourceData Source:=wksGraphTotal.Range("$A$2:$C$62")
```

> Object doesn't support this property or method

But if I click on the chart and choose "Select Data" in the Excel ribbon, I can set the Chart data range to `='Graph Total'!$A$2:$C$62` without a problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work.

```
wksGraphTotal.ChartObjects("TotQuestion").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=wksGraphTotal.Range("$A$2:$C$62")
```